# No Suitable method findViewById

Tags: java, android

So I am getting this error when I go to run the app, the thing is my webview code worked for my previous java files, all i did was change a digit in `ff1walkthrough` to `ff2walkthroug`h and `ff1` to `ff2`:

```
Error:(28, 36) error: no suitable method found for findViewById(WebView)
method Activity.<T>findViewById(int) is not applicable
(cannot infer type-variable(s) T
(argument mismatch; WebView cannot be converted to int))
method AppCompatActivity.findViewById(int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; WebView cannot be converted to int)
where T is a type-variable:
T extends View declared in method <T>findViewById(int)
```

my code:

FinalFantasy2.Java

```
package net.sunsetdevelopment.masteryourrpgs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class FinalFantasy2 extends AppCompatActivity {
WebView ff2walkthrough;

/* Go Back Function */
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (ff2walkthrough.canGoBack()){
        ff2walkthrough.goBack();
    }else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_final_fantasy2);
    ff2walkthrough = (WebView) findViewById(ff2walkthrough);

    /* Enable Javascript */
    ff2walkthrough.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ff2walkthrough.setFocusable(true);
    ff2walkthrough.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    /* Render Priority */
    ff2walkthrough.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    ff2walkthrough.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    ff2walkthrough.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    ff2walkthrough.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    ff2walkthrough.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    ff2walkthrough.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    /* URL */
    ff2walkthrough.loadUrl("link hidden for stackoverflow");
    ff2walkthrough.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    }




}
```

HomeScreen.Java

```
package net.sunsetdevelopment.masteryourrpgs;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

/* Declarations */
ImageButton ff1walkthrough;
ImageButton ff2walkthrough;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

    /* Final Fantasy 1 Walkthrough */
    ff1walkthrough = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ff1);

    ff1walkthrough.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intentLoadNewActivity = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, FinalFantasy1.class);
            startActivity(intentLoadNewActivity);
        }
    });

    /* Final Fantasy 2 Walkthrough */

    ff2walkthrough = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ff2);

    ff2walkthrough.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intentLoadNewActivity = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, FinalFantasy2.class);
            startActivity(intentLoadNewActivity);
        }
    });

}
}
```

activity_final_fantasy2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="net.sunsetdevelopment.masteryourrpgs.FinalFantasy2">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ff2walkthrough"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am still very new to Java Programming / Android App Development. I have barely read some books, just simply trying to learn by doing and following along to YouTube tutorials.

Thanks for your help, in advance.

Comment: See, you sometimes call `findViewById(R.id.ff2);` and in that case you are calling `findViewById(ff2walkthrough);`... you dont use the R.id

Comment: Also welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_final_fantasy2);
    ff2walkthrough = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.ff2walkthrough); //HERE IS THE ERROR

    /* Enable Javascript */
    ff2walkthrough.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ff2walkthrough.setFocusable(true);
    ff2walkthrough.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

    /* Render Priority */
    ff2walkthrough.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    ff2walkthrough.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    ff2walkthrough.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    ff2walkthrough.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    ff2walkthrough.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    ff2walkthrough.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    /* URL */
    ff2walkthrough.loadUrl("link hidden for stackoverflow");
    ff2walkthrough.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to add the reference to `R.id`, like this:

```
findViewById(R.id.ff2walkthrough);
```

Instead of just calling `ff2walkthrough`, for further reference check the [Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html) to know more about Android resources.